# Symply.py for getting coefficients for ALL combination of the variables of a multivariable polynomial

Tags: julia, sympy

How to get coefficients for ALL combinations of the variables of a multivariable polynomial using sympy.jl or another Julia package for symbolic computation?

Here is an example from MATLAB,

```
   syms a b y
   [cxy, txy] = coeffs(ax^2 + by, [y x], ‘All’)
   cxy =
   [ 0, 0, b]
   [ a, 0, 0]
   txy =
   [ x^2y, xy, y]
   [ x^2, x, 1]
```

My goal is to get

```
[ x^2y, xy, y]
[ x^2, x, 1]
```

instead of [x^2, y]

I asked the same question at
https://github.com/JuliaPy/SymPy.jl/issues/482
and
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/symply-jl-for-getting-coefficients-for-all-combination-of-the-variables-of-a-multivariable-polynomial/89091
but I think I should ask if this can be done using Sympy.py.

Using Julia, I tried the following,

```
   julia> @syms x, y, a, b
   julia> ff = sympy.Poly(ax^2 + by, (x,y))
   Poly(ax**2 + by, x, y, domain='ZZ[a,b]')
   julia> [prod(ff.gens.^i) for i in ff.monoms()]
   2-element Vector{Sym}:
   x^2
   y
```

Comment: This is a very strange format that you are asking for. Why do you want that?

Comment: Tweaking the expression in the OP, this one-line gives the desired result `[prod(ff.gens.^Tuple(I)) for I in CartesianIndices(tuple(UnitRange.(0,vec(reduce(max, hcat(collect.(ff.monoms())...), dims=1)))...))]`. I'll try to make it a little longer and less cryptic in an answer

Comment: Thank you @DanGetz How to generate your method to any number of variables with different degrees, e.g., x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + xyz + xy^2z? I've got "ERROR: LoadError: DimensionMismatch: arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 3 and 5 Stacktrace:". Please kindly see my following up post.

Answer (score 2):

This is a longer form rewrite of the one-liner in the comment.
It uses `Pipe.jl` to write expressions 'functionally', so familiarity with pipe operator (`|>`) and `Pipe.jl` will help.

```
using SymPy
using Pipe

@syms x, y, a, b
ff = sympy.Poly(a*x^2 + b*y, (x,y))

max_degrees = 
  @pipe ff.monoms() .|> collect |> hcat(_...) |> 
    reduce(max, _, dims=2) |> vec

degree_iter = 
  @pipe max_degrees .|> UnitRange(0, _) |> 
    tuple(_...) |> CartesianIndices

result = [prod(ff.gens.^Tuple(I)) for I in degree_iter] |> 
  reverse |> eachcol |> collect
```

or using more of the python methods:

```
[prod(ff.gens.^I) for 
  I in Iterators.product((0:d for d in ff.degree.(ff.gens))...)] |>
  reverse |> eachcol |> collect
```

Both give the desired result:

```
2-element Vector{...}:
 [x^2*y, x*y, y]
 [x^2, x, 1]
```

UPDATE:

In case there are more than 2 generators, the result needs to be a Array with higher dimension. The last bits of matrix transposes is immaterial and the expressions become:

Method 1:

```
max_degrees = 
  @pipe ff.monoms() .|> collect |> hcat(_...) |> 
    reduce(max, _, dims=2) |> vec

degree_iter = 
  @pipe max_degrees .|> UnitRange(0, _) |> 
    tuple(_...) |> CartesianIndices

result = [prod(ff.gens.^Tuple(I)) for I in degree_iter]
```

Method 2:

```
result = [prod(ff.gens.^Tuple(I)) for I in degree_iter]
```

Comment: using Pipe: @pipe works with Julia 1.8. When ff = sympy.Poly(a*x^2 + b*y + z^2 + x*y + y*z + x*z, (x, y, z)), I got "ERROR: DimensionMismatch: arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 3 and 6". Any chance you method can be generalised to any number of variables with any degrees?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Dan Getz. Your solution works for the TOY example from MATLAB. My real case is more complicated, which has more variables and polynominals. I tried your method for 3 variables,

```
using SymPy
@syms x, y, z, a, b

ff = sympy.Poly(a*x^2 + b*y + z^2 + x*y + y*z, (x, y, z))

[prod(ff.gens.^Tuple(I)) for I in CartesianIndices(tuple(UnitRange.(0,vec(reduce(max, hcat(collect.(ff.monoms())...), dims=1)))...))]
```

I got the following error,
ERROR: LoadError: DimensionMismatch: arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 3 and 5
Stacktrace:

How to generate your method to any number of variables with different degrees, e.g., x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + x*y*z + x*y^2*z?

Comment: Ah I see... the second method I wrote (and is used in this "answer") doesn't work for this case. The first method should work, but with `dims=2` instead of `dims=1` in first statement. Fixed this in answer. Also, avoid the last matrix manipulation in `result`. Thanks

Comment: The second method also works, as is, `[prod(ff.gens.^I) for 
  I in Iterators.product((0:d for d in ff.degree.(ff.gens))...)]`. Just remove the `|>
  reverse |> eachcol |> collect` from the ending (specific to two generators)

Comment: Both of your methods work. Thanks a lot @DanGetz

Answer (score -1):

You can find the degree of each of the two variables of interest and then use them to create the matrix of generators; you can use them to get the coefficients of interest. I am not sure what you expect if the equation were like `a*x**2 + b*y + c`...

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import a, b, x, y
>>> eq = a*x**2 + b*y
>>> deg = lambda x: Poly(eq, x).degree()  # helper to give degree in "x"
>>> v = (Matrix([x**i for i in range(deg(x),-1,-1)]
...        )*Matrix([y**i for i in range(deg(y),-1,-1)]).T).T; v
Matrix([[x**2*y, x*y, y], [x**2, x, 1]])
>>> Matrix(*v.shape, [eq.coeff(i) if i.free_symbols else eq.as_coeff_Add()[0]
...        for i in v])
Matrix([[0, 0, b], [a, 0, 0]])
```

From @jverzani (thanks)

```
using SymPy; 
@syms a b x y; 
eq = a*x^2 + b*y; 
deg = x -> sympy.Poly(eq, x).degree(); 
xs, ys = [x^i for i ∈ range(deg(x):-1:0], [y^i for i  ∈ deg(y):-1:0]; 
v = permutedims(xs .* permutedims(ys)); 
M = [x^2*y x*y y; x^2 x 1]; 
[length(free_symbols(i)) > 0 ? eq.coeff(i) : eq.as_coeff_add()[1] for i ∈ v];
[0 0 b; a 0 0]
```

Comment: The question bears `julia` tag and you're shooting a `python` script as an answer!

Comment: To the right of the `julia` tag is a `SymPy` tag. The author can judge whether this is helpful or not.

Comment: The question is asking about using sympy from julia. It is still useful to have an answer that shows how to do this in sympy so that someone can translate that to how you could do it using the julia wrapper.

Comment: Thank you. I am indeed using SymPy.jl. Since this question stems from SymPy.py, the answer could also help for the SymPy.jl case.

Comment: Just here to translate the code of @smichr into julia. (@smichr is a huge contributor to SymPy!). The following can be copied and pasted (comments don't allow the formatting it deserves): `using SymPy;
@syms a b x y;
eq = a*x^2 + b*y;
deg = x -> sympy.Poly(eq, x).degree();
xs, ys = [x^i for i ∈ range(deg(x):-1:0], [y^i for i  ∈ deg(y):-1:0];
v = permutedims(xs .* permutedims(ys));
M = [x^2*y x*y y; x^2 x 1];
[length(free_symbols(i)) > 0 ? eq.coeff(i) : eq.as_coeff_add()[1] for i ∈ v];
[0 0 b; a 0 0]`

Comment: I added your code to the answer above